# Tensorflow installation on windows 8 not working

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was very happy to see tensorflow's windows support. I am following the instructions on [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation-on-windows) link. The installation is successful, but while importing, it generates an error.
When I try to `import tensorflow as tf`, the following is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_ten
sorflow.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in impor
t_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.p
y", line 54, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_ten
sorflow.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_ten
sorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in impor
t_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", lin
e 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.p
y", line 60, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_ten
sorflow.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in impor
t_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.p
y", line 54, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_ten
sorflow.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_ten
sorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in impor
t_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'


Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using bazel,
you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory;
please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter
from there.
```

Any pointers on resolving the issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message means that one or more of the DLLs that TensorFlow depends on is not available on your computer. Installing the [Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3 (x64 version)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587) should fix this problem.

Note that this problem does not appear to arise if you have Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, or the Anaconda distribution of Python 3.5 installed. So far we have only heard of this problem affecting users of the Python.org distribution of Python 3.5. We are updating the documentation to reflect this, and it should be visible soon.

Comment: Great. This problem occurred to me as I use virtualenv in Windows 10. After installing the suggested distribution, the problem is directly solved; easy. Great answer!